# Set color for xticklabels individually in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

How can I give the labels "a", "b", "c" individual colors (e.g. "a" in green, "b" in blue, "c" in red) in the example below?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = plt.boxplot(np.random.normal(size=(10,3)))
ax.set_xticklabels(list("abc"))
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of boxplot without individually colored labels.]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    p = plt.boxplot(np.random.normal(size=(10,3)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(list("abc"))

[t.set_color(i) for (i,t) in
 zip(['red','green','blue'],ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels())]

plt.show()
```

Gives me:

[image]