# Customise polar contour plot axes style

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, polar-coordinates, contourf

I am using GridSpec to create a grid of polar contour plots in matplotlib. To aid with the visuals, I am trying the customise the appearance of the contour plots. See this single polar plot as an example (MWE below)

[image: polar contour plot]

I have two formatting questions in mind:

1. How can I customise the r axis to show only 0,20,40, and 60 values? How can I also make these numbers display in white?
2. When plotting multiple polar plots, I am choosing to remove the axes and ticks on the other by using `ax.grid(False)`, `ax.set_xticklabels([])`, and `ax.set_yticklabels([])`. However a white bar along theta = 0 remains, which I would like to remove. See this image as an example of what I mean:
   [image]

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec

gs=gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
gs.update(wspace=0.205, hspace=0.105) 
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(500/72.27,450/72.27))

X = np.arange(0, 70, 10)
Y = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 20))
r, theta = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z1 = np.random.random((Y.size, X.size))


ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0], projection='polar')
cax=ax.contourf(theta, r, Z1, 10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, can you show data on the second example as well?

Comment: @MyWork, I noticed the white bar doesn't show when I `plt.savefig`, so the second part doesn't appear to be an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, just use the [`rticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/projections_api.html#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes.set_rticks) from matplotlib (check out the [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html) too:

```py
ax.set_rticks([0,20,40,60])
ax.tick_params(colors='white', axis="y", which='both')
```

[image]

Full code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec

gs=gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
gs.update(wspace=0.205, hspace=0.105) 
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(500/72.27,450/72.27))

X = np.arange(0, 70, 10)
Y = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 20))
r, theta = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z1 = np.random.random((Y.size, X.size))


ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0], projection='polar')
cax=ax.contourf(theta, r, Z1, 10)

ax.set_rticks([0,20,40,60])
ax.tick_params(colors='white', axis="y", which='both') 
plt.show()
```

---

Update:
to have the ticks in a different colour, use what I mentioned in the comment:

```
colors = ['r', 'white', 'white', 'r']
for ytick, color in zip(ax.get_yticklabels(), colors):
    ytick.set_color(color)
```

Source: [matplotlib different colors for each axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617429/matplotlib-different-colors-for-each-axis-label/24617650), [Set color for xticklabels individually in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936014/set-color-for-xticklabels-individually-in-matplotlib)

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have some of the rtick values a different colour. I.e. notice how 0 is not very visible, is it possible to have just in red colour, while the others are white?

Comment: @Sid, does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617429/matplotlib-different-colors-for-each-axis-label/24617650 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936014/set-color-for-xticklabels-individually-in-matplotlib help you?

Comment: Yes, that does help thanks for posting the links!

Comment: @Sid I also updated the answer